# Wifi signal goes out randomly and is only fixed by restarting the computer

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet

I have an Acer laptop with Win7 on it that is three years old. I don't have the money for a new computer (which is why I have one corner of it duct taped together.) I use internet and very randomly, an I mean so random that I lose internet right after I turn on my computer or I could go hours without losing internet or anything in between.

I have tried updating the driver for it and downloading previous versions of the driver with nothing helping. I have attempted to change settings for the wireless card and seeing if anything changes and I still lose internet. Sometimes I lose internet I can still see all the different signals except the one I was connected to and sometimes I cannot see any signals at all. I know that this is not a router issue because it has happened on three different routers in three different cities all with different ISPs. If you need more information Please ask.

Comment: See [12 Tips for Troubleshooting Your Internet Connection](http://www.pcmag.com/slideshow/story/262550/12-tips-for-troubleshooting-your-internet-connection) and  
[How to Fix Your Wi-Fi Network: 7 Tips](http://www.pcworld.com/article/260524/how_to_fix_your_wi_fi_network_7_tips.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the channel by logging into your router’s web interface; generally by using an IP like 192.168.1.1 into the web browser, once you log in(contact your provider if you need login details), find the setup or wireless section then change your network to another channel. Most recommended channels are 1,6 and 11.

If this doesn't work then you can disable NetBIOS and check if the signal is stable.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313314

If nothing works out well, please take your laptop to nearby service center to ensure that there is no problem with the machine.

Comment: The issue happens with several different routers.

Answer (score 0):

**Your wireless card and/or antenna may be failing.** The facts that:

1. You've not been able to solve the problem by upgrading the drivers for your wireless card and,
2. You have the problem with multiple routers,

strongly suggest a hardware problem. First, check the antenna connections on your wireless card. If they are secure, then your next step would be to try a different card.

You can usually find a service manual on the Internet by searching for those terms plus the make & model of your laptop.

If opening your laptop isn't something you want to do, a local service shop will be able to do this for you.